# How to print lines that only contain characters from a list in BASH?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a file called "dictionary.txt" containing a list of all possible words, e.g.:

```
a
aardvark
act
anvil
ate
...
```

How can I search this, only printing lines containing letters from a limited list, e.g., if the list contains the letters "c", "a", and "t", a search will reveal these words:

```
a
act
cat
```

If the letters "e", "a", and "t" are searched, only these words are found from "dictionary.txt":

```
a
ate
eat
tea
```

The only solution I have managed is this:

- Create a list of all possible letters.
- Delete the searched letters from this list, leaving a list of letters that I do not want to search for.
- With a for loop cycling each of those letters, delete all lines from the dictionary that contains those letters.
- Print the remaining words found in the dictionary.

This solution is very slow. Also, I need to use this code with other languages, which have thousands of possible characters, so this search method is especially slow.

How can I print only those lines from "dictionary.txt" that only contain the searched-for-letters, and nothing else?

Comment: I don't see how my solution could be causing errors; you were vague in your use case description: "if the list contains the letters "c", "a", and "t", a search will reveal these words". Can you clarify how you're passing information to grep?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
grep '^[eat]*$' dictionary.txt
```

Explanation:

`^` = marker meaning beginning of line

`$` = marker meaning end of line

`[abc]` = character class ("match any one of these characters")

`*` = multiplier for character class (zero or more repetitions)

Comment: Oh yeah, and it's also fine to say `[cheated]` which will ignore repeated letters and act like `[cheatd]`

Comment: If this explicit form leads to `Argument list too long`, it's worth mentioning that the expression can also use ranges such as `[e-hk-oz]`. This may be helpful if the CJK characters in question have adjacent code points.

Comment: This could also apply to empty lines. Better use `\+` or `+` instead of `*`.

Comment: @konsolebox - Since when are there empty lines in dictionary wordlist files?

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, I cannot comment, otherwise I'd add to [amphetamachine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740535/2088135).  Anyway, with the updated condition of thousands of search characters you may want to do the following:

```
grep -f patterns.txt dictionary.txt
```

where `patterns.txt` is your regexp:

```
/^[eat]\+$/
```

Below is a sample session:

```
$ cat << EOF > dictionary.txt
> one
> two
> cat
> eat
> four
> tea
> five
> cheat
> EOF
$ cat << EOF > patterns.txt
> ^[eat]\+$
> EOF
$ grep -f patterns.txt dictionary.txt
eat
tea
$
```

This way you are not limited by the shell (Argument list too long).  Also, you can specify multiple patterns in the file:

```
$ cat patterns.txt
^[eat]\+$
^five$
$ grep -f patterns.txt dictionary.txt
eat
tea
five
$
```

Comment: using it with real linux dictionary file (consisting hundreds of thousands patterns) takes infinite amount of time to process even a few kb file :)

Comment: Well, the described case "hundreds of thousands" is just a wrong application for this pattern.

Answer (score 6):

Try it using `awk`:

```
awk '/^[eat]*$/ { print }' dictionary.txt
```

I found this to be at least an order of magnitude faster than grep for more than about 7 letters. However, I don't know if you will run into the same problem with thousands of letters, as I didn't test that many.

You can even search for multiple patterns at once (this is faster than searching each pattern one at a time, since the dictionary file will be read only once). Every pattern acts as an if statement:

```
awk '/^[eat]*$/ { print "[eat]: " $0 } /^[cat]*$/ { print "[cat]: " $0 }' dictionary.txt
```

Comment: Your first suggestion could be reduced to `awk '/^[eat]*$/' dictionary.txt` - the `{print}` is implicit.

Comment: @TomFenech That's handy!

Answer (score 5):

```
sed -n '/a/'p words.txt
```

Use this for whichever letter you need to find.  If you want to find more than one letter together, simply repeat the command.

Grep also should not be used for more than the most simple/elementary of searches, IMHO.  Although I normally hesitate to call any of the POSIX utilities obsolete, I do try and avoid grep.  Its' syntax is extremely inconsistent.

Studying this text file is also recommended. http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include e.g. Umlauts in the pattern and not want to have the other accents, set the `LC_ALL="C"` prior to executing the grep.

This e.g. will give you only the candidate German words in a potential dictionary.txt file.

```
LC_ALL="C" grep '^[a-zA-ZäÄöÖüÜß]*$' dictionary.txt
```